# Unsupported list TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the below code,

```
def latency(i):
   layer_macc = profile(model)
   #new_list=[float(i) for i in layer_macc]
   macc_layer=layer_macc[i]
   return macc_layer/(3.84*pow(10,11))
```

when I try to run the code I get below error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'.
```

I tried to convert the list into float but still not working.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think dividing a `list` by a `float` should do?  What do you expect a `list` converted to a `float` would *be*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace last two lines:

```
x=3.8*pow(10,11)
return [f/x for f in macc_layer]
```